# MACOS - How to connect to a 802.1x wifi without entering the password from terminal. Password can be pre-configured with a wifi-profile

Tags: macos, wifi

in Windows i'm using as below.
netsh wlan connect ssid=YOUR-WIFI-SSID name=PROFILE-NAME

Need similar for the mac os.

Answer (score 0):

I think it will depend on whether you have saved the WiFi password in your keychain but the basic command is `networksetup` as follows:

```
networksetup -setairportnetwork en0 YOUR_NETWORD_SSID
```

For more information, try:

```
man networksetup
```